# Messeging or Hangouts - Open Directly to List of People

Tags: contacts, sms

When I get a notification that I've gotten a new text message, I open Messaging to look. However, it opens usually to the last person I was sending texts to, which isn't always the person that I now want to look at. I then have to go back to get to the list, and then click the new message to read it.

Is there a way to have the app open directly to the list of people, every time? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried pressing the notification instead of opening the app directly?

Answer (score 0):

When you come out of the app pressing home button, it's state is stored. So no matter how many messages you get ,you still go the previous message you were looking at, if you press messaging app...  to prevent this, when you get a new message open notifications instead of messaging app.. This makes app refresh it's previous state to the current one..

Comment: That would go to the new message, not tje list of people. Which is better but not what s really am lookong for.

Comment: In that case you need to close the messaging app every time you leave. So that next time you get a new message, just click on the app. You'll be taken to the list of people